# Baricenter of a region bounded by a parametric curve

Tags: differential-geometry, parametric

I just want to ask if there exists a general rule to get the baricenter of a region bounded by a parametric curve?

Comment: So you are in 2D and the curve is piecewise smooth and closed?

Comment: Yes exactly that's my curve

Comment: Then better include that data in the question. Do you know the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem)?

Comment: Sorry, yes i do know it

Comment: For 2D, [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) is equivalent. The idea is analogous to the one used for [area calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Area_calculation). In fact, you'll need that one and a vector-valued integral that gives you the barycenter times the total area.

Comment: Idk things are yet not clear to me! Usually for a normal area bounded by a mapping say $f$ and the x-axis for x $\in [a,b]$ where $f$ is continuos and smooth on this domain, its baricenter coordinates are ($\frac{\int xf(x)dx}{M_{total}}$, $\frac{\int yf(x) dx}{M_{total}}$ ) but now idk how to handle this problem with a parametric curve

Comment: Can you explain me more your solution please

Comment: Would this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Bounded_region

Comment: I already know this way mate, but im not able to link it to solve such a question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846837/baricenter-of-a-region-bounded-by-a-closed-parametric-curve. That's my problem! Shall i just insert $y(t)$ instead of $f(x)$ and $x(t)$ instead of $x$ and integrate with respect to $t$?

Comment: For that specific problem, split the function into two parts:
$$y=\left(\frac{\cos^{-1}(x)}{2\pi}\right)-\left(\frac{\cos^{-1}(x)}{2\pi}\right‌​)^3$$
$$y=\left(1-\frac{\cos^{-1}(x)}{2\pi}\right)-\left(1-\frac{\cos^{-1}(x)}{2\pi}\r‌​ight)^3$$

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge a "wide" approach (don't dare to call it "general") would be as follows:

1. Determine if the curve does not intersect itself and does not retrace; in case, separate/limit the parameter excursion appropriately.
2. Call  $
   \mathbf{r} = \left( \begin{gathered}
     x \hfill \\
     y \hfill \\ 
   \end{gathered}  \right)$
   the position vector, $C$ the curve, $G$ the region enclosed by it, $A$ its area
   $A = \iint\limits_{\left( {x,y} \right)\, \in \;G} {dx\,dy}$
   then the baricenter (centroid) will be given by
   $\mathbf{b} = \frac{1}
   {A}\iint\limits_{\left( {x,y} \right)\, \in \;G} {\mathbf{r}\,dx\,dy}$
3. The baricentre of a composite figure is the "area-weighted" average of the baricenters of each portion.
   The same holds true in the limit so
   $$
   \mathbf{b} = \frac{1}
   {A}\int\limits_G {\mathbf{\beta }\,dA} 
   $$
   where $\mathbf{\beta }(x)$ is the baricenter of each infinitesimal portion of area $dA$, into which $G$ has been *exhaustively* decomposed.
4. Now, if the expressions for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ allow to be converted into *easily-integrable* $y(x)$ or $x(y)$, then use the double integral,.
   That is equivalent  to convert into stripes parallel to the $x$ (or $y$) axis, whose $\mathbf{\beta }(x)$ and $dA(x)$
   (or expressed in terms of $y$ or $t$) are easily determined, i.e. the integral in $dA$.
5. Instead, if the expressions for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ allow to be converted into *easily-integrable* polar coordinates
   $\rho$ and $\alpha$, then splitting the area into circular sectors, we can write
   $$
   \mathbf{b} = \frac{1}
   {A}\int\limits_{\left( {\rho ,\alpha } \right)\, \in \;C} {\left( \begin{gathered}
     2/3\,\rho \cos \alpha  \hfill \\
     2/3\,\rho \sin \alpha  \hfill \\ 
   \end{gathered}  \right)\frac{1}
   {2}\rho ^{\,2} \,d\alpha }  = \frac{1}
   {{3A}}\int\limits_{\left( {\rho ,\alpha } \right)\, \in \;C} {\left( \begin{gathered}
     \cos \alpha  \hfill \\
     \sin \alpha  \hfill \\ 
   \end{gathered}  \right)\rho ^{\,3} \,d\alpha } 
   $$
   6.The integral in $dA$ can also be put in an alternative way, considering that the area spanned by $ \mathbf{r} $
   can be written as
   $$
   dA = \frac{1}
   {2}\left| {\,\mathbf{r} \times d\mathbf{r}\,} \right|\quad \text{(with}\;\text{sign)} = \frac{1}
   {2}\left| {\,\begin{array}{*{20}c}
      x & y  \\
      {\frac{{dx}}
   {{dt}}} & {\frac{{dy}}
   {{dt}}}  \\
    \end{array} \,} \right|dt
   $$
   with baricenter $\mathbf{\beta } = \frac{2}{3}\mathbf{r}$
   Thus
   $$
   \mathbf{b} = \frac{1}
   {{3A}}\oint\limits_C {\mathbf{r}\left| {\,\begin{array}{*{20}c}
      x & y  \\
      {dx/dt} & {dy/dt}  \\
    \end{array} \,} \right|dt} 
   $$
   $ -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - $

Example:
Consider the semiparabolic sector comprised among the axes and the curve $C$
$$
C:\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1 \hfill \\
  x = t \hfill \\
  y = 1 - t^{\,2}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.\quad  \to \quad C:\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1 \hfill \\
  y = 1 - x^{\,2}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.\quad  \to \quad G:\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1 \hfill \\
  0 \leqslant y \leqslant 1 - x^{\,2}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$

Its area is 
$
A = \iint\limits_G {dx\,dy} = \int_{x = 0}^{\;1} {\left( {\int_{y = 0}^{\;1 - x^{\,2} } {dy} } \right)dx}  = \frac{2}{3}
$

and the baricenter will be
$$
\mathbf{b} = \frac{1}
{A}\iint\limits_G {\left( \begin{gathered}
  x \\ 
  y \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)dx\,dy} = \frac{3}
{2}\int_{x = 0}^{\;1} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  x\int_{y = 0}^{\;1 - x^{\,2} } {dy}  \\ 
  \int_{y = 0}^{\;1 - x^{\,2} } {y\,dy}  \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)dx}  = \frac{3}
{2}\int_{x = 0}^{\;1} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  x - x^{\,3}  \\ 
  \frac{{\left( {1 - x^{\,2} } \right)^{\,2} }}
{2} \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)dx}  = \left( \begin{gathered}
  \frac{3}
{8} \hfill \\
  \frac{2}
{5} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)
$$

or, otherwise
$$
\mathbf{b} = \frac{1}
{A}\int\limits_G {\mathbf{\beta }\,dA}  = \frac{3}
{2}\int_{x\, = \,0}^{\;1} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  x \\ 
  \left( {1 - x^{\,2} } \right)/2 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\,\left( {1 - x^{\,2} } \right)dx}  = \left( \begin{gathered}
  \frac{3}
{8} \\ 
  \frac{2}
{5} \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)
$$

and with the curve integral
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \mathbf{b} = \frac{1}
{{3A}}\oint\limits_C {\mathbf{r}\left| {\,\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   x & y  \\
   {dx/dt} & {dy/dt}  \\
 \end{array} \,} \right|dt}  = \frac{1}
{2}\oint\limits_C {\left( \begin{gathered}
  t \\ 
  1 - t^{\,2}  \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left| {\,\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   t & {1 - t^{\,2} }  \\
   1 & { - 2t}  \\
 \end{array} \,} \right|dt}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{2}\oint\limits_C {\left( \begin{gathered}
  t \\ 
  1 - t^{\,2}  \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( { - t^{\,2}  - 1} \right)dt}  = \frac{1}
{2}\left( {\int\limits_{y\, = \,0} {0\,dt}  + \int_{t\, = \,1}^{0\,} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  t\left( { - t^{\,2}  - 1} \right) \\ 
  \left( {1 - t^{\,2} } \right)\left( { - t^{\,2}  - 1} \right) \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)dt}  + \int\limits_{x\, = \,0} {0\,dt} } \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{2}\int_{t\, = \,0}^{\,1\,} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  t\left( {1 + t^{\,2} } \right) \\ 
  \left( {1 - t^{\,4} } \right) \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)dt}  = \frac{1}
{2}\left( \begin{gathered}
  \frac{1}
{2} + \frac{1}
{4} \\ 
  \left( {1 - \frac{1}
{5}} \right) \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) = \left( \begin{gathered}
  \frac{3}
{8} \\ 
  \frac{2}
{5} \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

Comment: Another example is provided in answering to <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848225>